# How to write code which has a leading sequence of spaces within a comment?

Tags: support

On the main site of TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange within comments<sup>1</sup> you can use backticks `` `code` `` for writing code.

Seems this does not work when the piece of code has a leading sequence of spaces.

E.g., typing  `` `      code` `` within a comment<sup>1</sup> does not work out.

How to write code which has a leading sequence of spaces within a comment<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Comment—the kind of short message which you can write after clicking on "Add a comment".</sub>

Comment: Good question.  Starting with `&nbsp;` doesn't work either.

Comment: `​    abc xyz 123`

Comment: as above but it doesn't really start with a space (has zwsp at the start) so will mess up if someone cuts and pastes it to code)

Comment: also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83522/preserving-white-space-in-comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a zero width space (eg U+200b) at the start

> `​    abc xyz 123`

That looks the nicest, but if you are expecting someone to copy the code as code it will have the unicode space character and give errors or warnings most likely.

So it is probably best to use a visible marker and tell the user to omit it as in

> the code between the two `|`.        `|         abc xyz 123|`

Note this is network wide (and been asked for and rejected on the network meta), eg

[Preserving white space in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83522/preserving-white-space-in-comments)

so nothing that can be changed here.